# SFML 2.2 Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA622C21F9(sfml-system-2.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I'm trying to build a game in sfml under windows 10.It shows successful at the time of building.whenever i debug the solution it shows the error message like:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA622C21F9 (sfml-system-2.dll) in picpuz2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000019.
```

Under call stack the program stopped at the code:

```
window.create(sf::VideoMode(300, 300, 32), "PICPUZ");
```

This is my code:

Comment: Wait.... Where is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the tutorials closely. If you are doing a debug build, you should link with the dlls that end in `-d` for debug.

For example `sfml-system-d-2.dll`

Linking release and/or debug to the wrong configuration (release to debug or debug to release) will result in unpredictable crashes.